# How to replace the Object in the "new" Operation?

Tags: java

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}
```

now in some function:

```
A a = new A();
```

I want this result is replaced into a B object without changing my code.How can I do it?

Comment: The problematic part is "without changing my code"

Comment: You cannot assign an object of type `A` to a variable declared as type `B`. It only works the other way around: Because `B` is (also) an `A`, you can assign an object of type `B` to a variable of type `A`.

Comment: If you can't change this code, rename the class name. A become B and B become A. But this will be a nightmare!

Comment: @AxelH: LOL! That's creative.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, there is always a solution ;) but not necessary a good one! I admit I didn't take that question seriously...

Comment: You can check this link to know about factory pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: thanks,I know how to use factory method and inheritance to solve it,but it does not work in my case.Cause the source code is given by others,but I want to change part of its implementation.

Answer (score 3):

> I want this result replaced into a B object...

If you're asking for the result of `new A()` to be a `B` instance, you can't do that in Java. There is no mechanism for it. You will *have* to change your code so that it either calls a `B` constructor, or calls some factory method that calls a `B` constructor. The variable can still be typed `A` if appropriate.

Comment: thanks,I know how to use factory method and inheritance to solve it,but it does not work in my case.Cause the source code is given by others,but I want to change part of its implementation.

Comment: @denbard: I'm afraid that's where the "you can't do that in Java" comes in. :-) You have to change the source code (or change the bytecode after compilation).

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to change a bit of code, like :

```
A a = new B();
```